# Can't find testhost.deps.json in ASP .NET Core MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to run integration testing in my ASP .NET Core MVC Application. But i get this error where running tests :

> `Can't find '/My_Project/bin/Debug/net7.0/testhost.deps.json'. This file is required for functional tests to run properly. There should be a copy of the file on your source project bin folder. If that is not the case, make sure that the property PreserveCompilationContext is set to true on your project file. E.g '<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>'.`

I added

> `<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>`

in my .csproj file, but after that I have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try add this to your .cspoj

```
      <ItemGroup>
        <InternalsVisibleTo Include="Your_Project_Name" />
      </ItemGroup>
```